# Use inputs variable as a tag in composite action

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I have a composite action like this and I want to pass input tag to a step:
I tried this code but I get an error unrecognized inputs value inputs.tag

```
inputs:
  tag:
     required: false
     description: "java tag version"
     default: 11
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: Build 
      id: build
      uses: docker://openjdk:${{ inputs.tag }}
…
```

Comment: Do you work in the main branch? If not make sure you run the action from the correct branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action code is invalid. You are missing a `description` field and you have to set your `default` value to a string

```
inputs:
  tag:
     required: false
     description: "My image tag"
     default: "11"
```

Also, if the input is required, you don't need the `default` value.

From the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#inputs):

> `inputs.<input_id>.description`
> **Required** A `string` description of the input parameter.
>
> `inputs.<input_id>.required`
> Optional A boolean to indicate whether the action requires the input parameter. Set to true when the parameter is
> required.
>
> `inputs.<input_id>.default`
> Optional **A string** representing the default value. The default value is used when an input parameter isn't specified in a workflow file.

---

Edit:

Apparently, you can't use expressions in action names as it's been discussed [in this issue](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/9049#discussioncomment-2695844) and [this](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25246):

> In order to enact policies like only using actions defined in the org or repo we can’t allow actions to dynamically change at runtime.  So using any sort of dynamic value in uses is not something we will be able to support.

So the variable in

```
uses: docker://openjdk:${{ inputs.tag }}
```

won't work, there's a hack/workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/9049#discussioncomment-4239509), feel free if you want to consider it. But overall it seems to be a bad practice to have dynamic image tags or action versions.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn’t put the description but I have it in my real code. I tried the default value with "11" with " and without " and I get the same error

Comment: Would you update your post with an example of the calling workflow, maybe you are passing a wrong value from there

Comment: I updated my answer above, looks like we can't use expressions and variables in action names: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/9049#discussioncomment-4239509. And now [GH](https://www.githubstatus.com/incidents/qfby3shb6r3w) is experiencing some issues so I can't test if that still the case

Comment: Yes github is facing an incident. I have in mind a workaround with strategy.matrix and I saw it in the discussion link. Thank you I will try it tomorrow

Comment: Please check this [comment from a PO at Github](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25246#discussioncomment-3247073), he explained why they don't allow variables in action names